# How can I form REGEX in command line utility of youtube-dl to ignore certain keywords from playlist?

Tags: regex, youtube-dl

How can I form REGEX in command line utility of youtube-dl to ignore certain keywords from playlist. Moreover, are RegEx same as in BASh and Java?

Comment: You have potentially told us certain keywords which you don't want to match.  But, what is the whitelist and what _do_ you want to match?

Comment: thanks for answering, youtube-dl has the option to include or ignore videos containing certain keywords. I was downloading a playlist from a cooking sites account and ignore all videos that contains word say [astrisk]chicken[asterisk] or [asterisk]mutton[asterisk] for e.g. where *= an arbitrary string of numbers or characters.. So how should i form the RegEx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

youtube-dl uses the Python [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library, which is substantially compatible to the regular expressions in Java and bash.

For example, to match only videos with titles containing `chicken` or `noodles` in a YouTube search for `recipe`, you can use

```
youtube-dl ytsearch20:recipe --match-title '(chicken|noodles)'
```